# Jquery change select value not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to set the select option with jquery but it's not working properly. It actually set the value but the text is not updated.

I have tried with `.prop('selected',true)`, `.attr('selected',true)`, `.prop('selected','selected')`, `.val()` and `.val().change()` but nothig seems to work

Here is the select

```
<select class="input-field" id="equip_type" name="equip_type">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo de Equipo </option> 
    <option value="0">equip_type_other</option>
    <option value="1">equip_type_desktop</option>
    <option value="2">equip_type_laptop</option>
    <option value="3">equip_type_tablet</option>
    <option value="4">equip_type_printer</option>
</select>
```

I'm going to set the option within an ajax function, so the value came from the function. This is what I'm currently trying

```
$('#equip_type').val(data.equipType).change();
```

I have use the same method with other forms, but just this one is causing this truble. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'd recommend just giving the actual rendered HTML that is on the webpage.

Comment: can you show us your `change()` method. Also make sure `data.equipType` is equal to the value you have in html once it is rendered.

Comment: I'm sure the data.equipType is equal to the value. I use the console.log to display the data.equipType and the selected value, that is how I know that the value is actually changing, but not the text

Comment: @bipen, change is an event, not method, so here change do nothing

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I added the rendered HTML

Comment: @CarlosSchuldiner Simply using `.val(value)` should work ([example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70vc0o4f/1/)). There is no reason to call the `.change()` method if you never setup the event handler. What's the value of `data.equipType` here? It needs to be the value of the `value` attributes and not the text inside the `<option>` elements.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Yes it is a method by definition, it calls the `change` event handler for that element.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev ..  I meant to give us the code that OP has in change event. If he has nothing on it then its usual to trigger `change()`

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#equip_type').val(data.equipType).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 5):

This is enough:

```
$('#equip_type').val(data.equipType)
```

But, you have:

```
<option value="${equipType.value}">${equipType.toString()}</option>
```

and this is the problem, the parameter of .val() must be the value of the option field, instead you use the text value.

So, you may filter:

```
        $('#equip_type option').filter(function() {
            return this.textContent == 'equip_type_tablet'
        }).prop('selected', true);
```

My snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#equip_type option').filter(function() {
    return this.textContent == 'equip_type_tablet'
  }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="input-field" id="equip_type" name="equip_type">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo de Equipo </option>
    <option value="0">equip_type_other</option>
    <option value="1">equip_type_desktop</option>
    <option value="2">equip_type_laptop</option>
    <option value="3">equip_type_tablet</option>
    <option value="4">equip_type_printer</option>
</select>
```

Comment: nice catch ... +1

Comment: I get the same result. It successfully change the value of the select. But the text doesn't update. I mean. The value change to "3" but the text says "Tipo de Equipo". I really don't know what could be wrong

Comment: Yeah, I'm actally doing that. I use the console.log to display the `data.equipType` and then to display the `$('#equip_type').val()` and it coincide

Comment: Do you try to select more than one time the option?

Comment: The last question: do you execute a line like: $('#equip_type option').text('');? In other words, because the text does not change, could you execute: document.getElementById('equip_type').selectedIndex, just to see the selected option?

Comment: I'm not using the `.text(")` function. And with the `document.getElementById('equip_type').selectedIndex` the index changed as well.

In the end, the answer is that I was missing one class on the select. Since I'm using Material Design I guess is important but I don't understant why is necesary for this to work.

Anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
$('option:selected', '#my_select').val();
```

First parameter selector for selected child element, second - for parent. Then call val() method to get value for selected child of select with my_select as id.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47669687/edit) to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#equip_type option[value="value"]');
```

In the value you can please option value and it will work.

Comment: This method to get, not set